# Leibniz rule for improper integrals

Tags: calculus, derivatives, improper-integrals

Can someone state the conditions under which I can apply Leibniz integral rule to an improper integral in which both endpoints approach approach limits? 
I saw this subject has been discussed elsewhere but I saw diffrent answers and these conditions are not clear to me. Thank you